# Prometheus filtering based on Labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana

How to add label filters in Prometheus query?

**kube_pod_info**

> kube_pod_info{created_by_kind="ReplicaSet",created_by_name="alertmanager-6d9f74d4c5",instance="kube-state-metrics:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=“test",pod="alertmanager-6d9f74d4c5-xlqrv"}

**kube_pod_labels**

> kube_pod_labels{instance="kube-state-metrics:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_app="alertmanager",label_pod_template_hash="6d9f74d4c5",namespace=“test",pod="alertmanager-6d9f74d4c5-xlqrv”,label_source=“k8s"}

Here, I have kube state metrics info in prometheus for kube_pod_info & kube_pod_labels.

`kube_pod_info{namespace="test"}`  ---> Filters pods by namespace test.

Here, I want to include filter based on labels as well. I have a label called "label_source=“k8s" in kube_pod_labels. How can I join kube_pod_info & kube_pod_labels to apply label filter as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+` operator to join metrics. Here, `group_left()` will include the extra label: `label_source` from the right metric `kube_pod_labels`. The metric you're joining is forced to zero ( i.e. `0 * kube_pod_labels` ) so that it doesn't affect the result of first metric.

```
(
kube_pod_info{namespace="test"}
)
   + on(namespace) group_left(label_source)
(
   0 * kube_pod_labels
)
```

Comment: Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {namespace="test1"} on the right hand-side of the operation: ...
.....
many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

Comment: @user1578872, yes, this is intended. You need to join two metrics by unique label. Like, `on(instance) group_left(label_source)`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the "Join Metrics" documentation [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/docs), you can essentially combine the labels from the `kube_pod_info` query with those of the `kube_pod_labels` query.

Something along the lines of this:

```
kube_pod_info{namespace="test"} * on (namespace, pod) group_left() kube_pod_labels{label_source="k8s"}
```

This query should give you all of the pods in the namespace `test`, which have the `source` label set to `k8s`.