# Prometheus kubelet metrics with pod labels

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, kubelet, kube-prometheus-stack

I am trying to figure out **how to get pod labels into the metric tags from kubelet metrics using prometheus-stack**. In our environment, we need to hash pod names (due to length limitations) so our app name, env, and unit name are saved in pod labels.

We are using prometheus-stack (helm installation) to collect metrics from kubelet (`/metrics`, `/metrics/cadvisor`) and due to the lack of pod labels in metrics tags, it's difficult to know which metric belongs to which application.

Prometheus-stack is using `sd_kubernetes_config` with endpoint rule to collect kubelet metrics, where `__meta` tags for pod labels cannot be used. Is there another way how to get that labels in metric tags?

I also tried to collect pod_labels metric using `kubeStateMetrics`, where I can get metric that contains pod labels, but I cannot figure out how to display both metrics in a way that metric from cadvisor will show its value and metric from `kubeStateMetrics` will be used to display its labels (in Prometheus graph).

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you try to filter metrics [based on pod labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067654/prometheus-filtering-based-on-labels)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that looks like it's working. We are using influxdb as the backend storage, and there that query I pretty nasty, so I am trying to achieve that without using join when displaying metrics.

Comment: Is it possible to make your query much pretty? As far as I know this filtering is the key to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can really use filtering metrics [based on pod labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067654/prometheus-filtering-based-on-labels). Look at the original answer:

> You can use  `+`  operator to join metrics. Here,  `group_left()`  will include the extra label:  `label_source`  from the right metric  `kube_pod_labels`. The metric you're joining is forced to zero ( i.e.  `0 * kube_pod_labels`  ) so that it doesn't affect the result of first metric.

```
(
kube_pod_info{namespace="test"}
)
   + on(namespace) group_left(label_source)
(
   0 * kube_pod_labels
)
```

In fact, metrics then can be long and nasty. However, it is an effective method in prometheus to create what you expect, which is kubelet metrics with pod labels.

Look also at [this guide](https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2020/02/21/how-to-join-prometheus-metrics-by-label-with-promql/) - it is described how to join Prometheus metrics by label with PromQL and [this another guide](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/04/how-to-use-promql-joins-for-more-effective-queries-of-prometheus-metrics-at-scale/) - How to use PromQL joins for more effective queries of Prometheus metrics at scale.

Comment: Yes, that's far as I discovered the only solution. There is no option how to add pod labels in kubelet metrics tags.